# Is there a way to start an application, in a docker container, during deployment to Kubernetes, using Helm?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, cicd

I am trying to avoid having to create three different images for separate deployment environments.

Some context on our current ci/cd pipeline:

For the CI portion, we build our app into a docker container and then submit that container to a security scan. Once the security scan is successful, the container gets put into a private container repository.

For the CD portion, using helm charts, we pull the container from the repository and then deploy to a company managed Kubernetes cluster.

There was an ask and the solution was to use a piece of software in the container. And for some reason (I'm the devops person and not the software engineer) the software needs environment variables (specific to the deployment environment) passed to it when it starts. How would we be able to start and pass environment variables to this software at deployment?

I could just create three different images with the environment variables but I feel like that is an anti-pattern. It takes away from the flexibility of having one image that can be deployed to different environments.

Can any one point me to resources that can accomplish starting an application with specific environment variables using Helm? I've looked but did not find a solution or anything that pointed me to the right direction. As a plan b, I'll just create three different images but I want to make sure that there is not a better way.

Comment: The Kubernetes documentation to [Define Environment Variables for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) might be a good starting point.  The Helm documentation on [Values Files](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) has a straightforward example of injecting a deploy-time Helm value into a ConfigMap.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the container orchestration, you can pass the env in differnt ways:

**Plain docker**:

```
docker run -e MY_VAR=MY_VAL <image>
```

**Docker compose:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: '<image>'
    environment:
      - MY_VAR=my-value
```

Check on [docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers)

**Kubernetes:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: <image>
    env:
    - name: MY_VAR
      value: "my value"
```

Check on [kubernetes-docu](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container)

**Helm:**

Add the values in your `values.yaml`:

```
myKey: myValue
```

Then reference it in your helm template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: <image>
    env:
    - name: MY_VAR
      value: {{ .Values.myKey }}
```

Check out the [helm docs](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm actually looking for how to start an application, in a container, at deployment time to Kubernetes, using a helm chart. Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: What do you mean by "deployment time"? When you deploy an application to kubernetes, it starts. You could use an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) in your pod, which will run before the actual "main" containers start.

Comment: This just may be what I need. I talked to the developer more and I understand the issue better. We need a Linux utility (blobfuser) to be run before the main application runs so I think an `init container` would be the ticket. Thank you again!

Comment: Actually, I [think this is what I need;](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/) being able to run a command in the container as it starts. `blobfuser` needs to be run to create a mount point and file system that the main application can connect to.